# To find optical flow as ndarray using cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video, opticalflow

I need to find the optical flow between every 2 adjacent frames of a video using Lucas Kanade's optical flow. I'm using Python and openCV for the project.

As per my understanding, Lucas Kanade is a sparse method to find optical flow. Is there a dense implementation of it? If so, how to use it in Python?

Using cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(), which is a dense method, we get as output an ndarray ('flow' in the below example) which contains the optical flow.

```
cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev, next, pyr_scale, levels, winsize, iterations, poly_n, poly_sigma, flags[, flow]) → flow
```

Is there a way to get similar output using cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()?

```
cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevImg, nextImg, prevPts[, nextPts[, status[, err[, winSize[, maxLevel[, criteria[, flags[, minEigThreshold]]]]]]]]) → nextPts, status, err
```

When using cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() (above), the output obtained contains nextPts which contains the next points to track but it does not directly give the optical flow of the 2 frames. If I subtract the prevPts from the nextPts, is the result the optical flow between the two frames?
I found ' prev(y,x)~next(y+flow(y,x)[1],x+flow(y,x)[0]) ' in the section explaining calcOpticalFlowFarneback() in this link: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html hence the question. (The syntax for both cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() and cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback are also from this link)
Below is my implementation of the same.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import subprocess as sp

yuv_filename = 'can_0.yuv'
flow=[]

width, height = 320, 240

file_size = os.path.getsize(yuv_filename)
n_frames = file_size // (width*height*3 // 2)
f = open(yuv_filename, 'rb')


old_yuv = np.frombuffer(f.read(width*height*3//2), dtype=np.uint8).reshape((height*3//2, width))


# Convert YUV420 to Grayscale
old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2GRAY_I420)


# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                       qualityLevel = 0.3,
                       minDistance = 7,
                       blockSize = 7 )

# Parameters for lucas kanade optical flow
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
                  maxLevel = 2,
                  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))


p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)


for i in range(1,n_frames):
    # Read Y, U and V color channels and reshape to height*1.5 x width numpy array
    yuv = np.frombuffer(f.read(width*height*3//2), dtype=np.uint8).reshape((height*3//2, width))

    # Convert YUV420 to Grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2GRAY_I420)

    # calculate optical flow
    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, gray, p0, None, **lk_params)


    flow.append(np.subtract(p1,p0))
    good_old = p0[st==1]
    good_new = p1[st==1]

    
    # Now update the previous frame and previous points
    old_gray = gray.copy()
    p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)


f.close()
```

Is flow a list of ndarrays containing the optical flow between adjacent frames of the input video?

This is the output I got for flow[7] (randomly selected) but I'm not sure if these are optical flow values.

````
[[[ 6.7138672e-03  4.5318604e-03]]

 [[-1.6220093e-02  1.9645691e-03]]

 [[-8.5296631e-03  1.8482208e-03]]

 [[-5.8441162e-03  1.5701294e-02]]

 [[ 7.5836182e-03  2.3475647e-02]]

 [[-1.4129639e-02  1.6357422e-02]]

 [[ 4.4555664e-03  4.1809082e-03]]

 [[ 5.6457520e-04 -9.5863342e-03]]

 [[ 2.8991699e-04 -3.0517578e-05]]

 [[-2.3452759e-02 -1.5502930e-02]]

 [[-6.8283081e-03  3.3264160e-03]]

 [[-8.4381104e-03  7.7590942e-03]]

 [[ 5.7144165e-03  1.1177063e-02]]

 [[-1.4160156e-02  2.1179199e-02]]

 [[-1.0498047e-02  8.0099106e-03]]

 [[-1.8310547e-04  2.8953552e-03]]

 [[ 4.4937134e-03 -2.0904541e-03]]

 [[-4.7698975e-02  3.7708282e-02]]

 [[ 6.3323975e-03  1.3298035e-02]]

 [[-3.3233643e-02 -1.7229080e-02]]

 [[ 7.5683594e-03  2.4566650e-03]]

 [[-3.0364990e-03  3.4656525e-03]]

 [[-1.0345459e-02 -7.4539185e-03]]

 [[ 1.3168335e-02  2.1423340e-02]]

 [[-6.3476562e-03 -1.0681152e-02]]

 [[ 1.5869141e-03  1.0375977e-03]]

 [[ 2.1820068e-03  6.7329407e-03]]

 [[-9.6130371e-03  2.9449463e-03]]

 [[-2.1362305e-03  8.5525513e-03]]

 [[-1.7547607e-04  2.1362305e-04]]

 [[ 2.9144287e-03  1.4343262e-03]]

 [[ 2.9602051e-03 -7.1868896e-03]]

 [[-1.2878418e-02  5.0182343e-03]]

 [[-3.1585693e-03 -5.0544739e-05]]

 [[ 1.0070801e-03  1.3740540e-02]]

 [[ 6.7138672e-04  1.7852783e-03]]

 [[-2.0568848e-02 -1.2943268e-02]]

 [[-2.1057129e-03  4.5013428e-03]]]```

Also is there a way to get optical flow using the Lucas Kanade method such that it has the same size or dimensions as the input frames? If so how?
````

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate a dense flow field with the pure pyramidal Lucas Kanade method by computing for each pixel the corresponding point pairs. To do that:

- ignore cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack
- initialize point list p0 that contains all pixel locations of the image

  ```
  grid_y, grid_x = np.mgrid[0:prevImg.shape[0]:1, 0:prevImg.shape[1]:1]
  p0 = np.stack((grid_x.flatten(),grid_y.flatten()),axis=1).astype(np.float32)
  ```
- run the spare flow computation

  ```
  p1, status, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevImg, currImg, p0, None)
  ```
- assemble dense flow field by computing and reshape motion vectors (p1 - p0) flow will have the shape (h x w x 2) and prevImg (h x w x 1)

  ```
  flow = np.reshape(p1 - p0, (prevImg.shape[0], prevImg.shape[1], 2))
  ```

However, this is not the most efficient way to compute a dense optical flow field. In OpenCV you may take a look to other [DenseOpticalFlow methods](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/df/dde/classcv_1_1DenseOpticalFlow.html) (e.g. DIS, Farneback, RLOFDense, Dual-TVL1)

Comment: Is there a way to calculate sparse optical flow such that the flow vector has the same size dimensions as the frames for which it is being calculated?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use sparse optical flow?

Comment: I have added some example code. If you use the following code: flow = cv2.optflow.calcOpticalFlowDenseRLOF(prevImg, currImg, None, forwardBackwardThreshold = -1, gridStep=(1,1)) this will do the same for the sparse RLOF but internaly. But please not this function needs prevImg and currImg to be RGB and Grayvalue as the pyramidalLucasKanade

Comment: Yes, I need to use sparse optical flow, specifically the Lucas Kanade optical flow (unless there is a dense implementation of it? If so, let me know). I'm trying to implement this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8325419       In Section 4 Part B it says " For a video sequence with N frames, we firstly extract all individual frames and compute the Lucas Kanade OF of every two adjacent frames i and i+1 (i=1, 2, …, N-1), obtaining OXi matrices in X direction and OYi in Y direction. "

Comment: Then again in Section 4 Part C Sub-part 1 it says "Note that OX and OY have the same size with the video frame image, meaning the calculation of the OF correlation coefficients will be heavy. "    I'm confused as to how to do this.  In my current implementation, I used Farneback algorithm (the calcOpticalFlowfarneback() method) but the calculation of correlation matrix (mentioned in the paper) is time consuming. So I was wondering if there was a way to do it exactly as mentioned in the paper. It is mentioned in the paper that they used C/C++. Maybe they wrote their own function for it?

Comment: Well the pyramidal Lucas Kanade function takes it time. I don't think that they will have a more optimized version. However, the authors does not provide any parameter setting of the Lucas Kanade. E.g. if you reduce the no of levels and reduces the winSize or iteration you can reduce the runtime drastically.

Comment: Hey you tried my proposal above for dense lucas kanade motion estimaton. But I think that version be slow too unless you chance the PLK parameters. But, the computation of the correlation matrixe itself should be quite fast.